# Prove that $T^{*}$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

> Let be $V$ and $W$ vector spaces of finit dimension over $\mathbb{C}$
> with inner product $\left \langle    ,  \right \rangle_{v}$ and $\left
>  \langle , \right \rangle_{w}$ respectively. Consider $T:V \rightarrow
>  W$ a surjective linear transformation such that exists $T^{*}:W
>  \rightarrow V$ and $\left \langle Tv,w \right \rangle_{w}=\left
>  \langle v,T^{*}w \right \rangle_{v}$,  $\forall v\in V$ and $w \in W$
>
> Prove that $T^{*}$ is injective

- **My attempt to prove if $T^{*}$ is injective:**

Let be $w_1, w_2 \in W$ such that $T^{*}w_1=T^{*}w_2$, that implies that

\begin{align}
\left \langle v, T^{*}w_1\right \rangle_{v}&=\left \langle v, T^{*}w_2\right \rangle_{v} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \forall v \in V\\ \iff \left \langle Tv, w_1\right \rangle_{w}&=\left \langle Tv, w_2\right \rangle_{w}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ w_1&=w_2\\ \therefore T^{*}& \text{ is injective}
\end{align}

Am I correct? I would really appreciate your help!

---

**Update:**

Let be $w_1, w_2 \in W$ such that $T^{*}w_1=T^{*}w_2$.

$\forall v \in V$, we have that:
\begin{align}
0&=\left \langle v, 0\right \rangle_{v}\\&=\left \langle v, T^{*}w_1-T^{*}w_2\right \rangle_{v}\\&=\left \langle v, T^{*}(w_1-w_2)\right \rangle_{v}\\&=\left \langle Tv, w_1-w_2\right \rangle_{w}
\end{align}

We have, $\left \langle Tv, w_1-w_2\right \rangle_{v}=0$, but $T$ is surjective, and that means that $\forall w\in W, \exists v \in V$, such that $w=Tv$.

That implies that there exists $v^{'} \in V$ such that $Tv^{'}=(w_1-w_2)\in W$. And

\begin{align}
\left \langle Tv^{'}, w_1-w_2\right \rangle_{w}&=\left \langle w_1-w_2, w_1-w_2\right \rangle_{w}=0\\ \iff w_1-w_2&=0 \iff w_1 = w_2
\end{align}
Would it be okay like this?

Comment: A priori $\left<Tv,w_1\right>=\left<Tv,w_2\right>$ for all $v$ doesn't implies that $w_1=w_2$. Here it indeed works, but you have to justify why.

Comment: Remark: you didn't use the fact that $T$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Surb, please see my update.

Comment: @azif00 Hi! How can I use it? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What's the difference between the updated proof and the original proof ? Both are the same and wrong. I think that @azif00 gave you a strong hint to correct your proof.

Comment: @luisegf **Hint**: $w_1=w_2$ iff $\langle w,w_1 \rangle_W = \langle w,w_2 \rangle_W$ for any $w \in W$ (*Proof*: if $\langle w,w_1-w_2 \rangle_W =  \langle w,w_1 \rangle_W - \langle w,w_2 \rangle_W = 0$ for any $w \in W$, in particular $\langle w_1-w_2,w_1-w_2 \rangle_W = 0$, which of course implies that $w_1-w_2=0$ by the properties of $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_W$.)

Comment: @azif00 Can you see my update again please? I've tried with the hint you gave me. Thank you very much

Comment: @Surb Please check my update again, I've tried with the hint that azif00 gave me.

Comment: It works. An other way would be : you have that $\left< Tv,w_1\right>=\left<Tv,w_2\right>$ for all $v\in V$. Since $T$ is surjective, you get that $\left<w,w_1\right> =\left<w,w_2\right>$ for all $w\in W$, and thus $w_1=w_2$. @luisegf

Comment: @Surb I am very grateful for your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do folks insist on **not** taking advantage of the fact that injectivity of linear transformations can be checked at $\mathbf{0}$?

Say $T^*\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}$. We just need to show that this implies that $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}$.

Let $\mathbf{v}$ be such that $T\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{w}$ (using surjectivity of $T$). Then
$$0 = \langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{0}\rangle = \langle \mathbf{v},T^*\mathbf{w}\rangle = \langle T\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}\rangle = \langle\mathbf{w},\mathbf{w}\rangle.$$
Therefore, $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{0}$, so $T^*$ is injective.